# Сравнение двух json-объектов и добавление недостающих элементов

Tags: jquery, json

Есть два json-объекта с разным количеством элементов. В первом, допустим, 6 элементов с ключом `segment`, а во втором - 8. Можно ли как-то сравнить эти два json-объекта таким образом, чтобы алгоритм добавил к первому объекту 2 недостающих `segment` из второго? И насколько это ресурсо-затратно будет на клиенте?

Comment: Один ключ на уровне, не больше.

Comment: @Other это касаемо производительности?

Comment: Это касаемо логики. Любой парсер затрёт все значения одного ключа на последнее (обычно). Т. е. `{"segment": 1, "segment": "segment": 42}` => `Obj{segment: 42}`.

Comment: @Other а если считать количество таких элементов и сравнивать их количество в обеих массивах?

Comment: Что считать-то? Ключ будет один, сколько бы не вставили в JSON.

Comment: @Other а если элементы будут без ключей? Просто `[{},{},{}]`

Comment: Будут три объекта в массиве, изучите матчасть, Бога ради.

Comment: `Есть 2 массива с объектами, в первом 6 объектов с ключом segment, во втором 8. Как добавить в первый массив недостающие объекты из второго?` - я всё правильно понял? Циклом пройти и добавить. Для линейной асимптотики имеет смысл имеющиеся значения segment собрать предварительно.

Comment: @vp_arth да, вы всё верно поняли. Но у меня проблема не с пониманием самого алгоритма, а с его реализацией. Мне не хватает знаний в JS, чтобы понять, как можно определить, является ли какой-то массив недостающим или нет. Вот в чём всё дело.

Comment: Может вам [это](http://jsonpatch.com/) нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Циклом пройти и добавить.
Для линейной асимптотики имеет смысл имеющиеся значения segment собрать предварительно.

```js
let arr1 = [
  {seg: 1},
  {seg: 3},
  {seg: 5}
];

let arr2 = [
  {seg: 1},
  {seg: 2},
  {seg: 4}
];
// Собираем ключи из первого массива
let seglist = arr1.reduce((o, el) => (o[el.seg] = true, o), {});
// Проходим по второму
arr2.forEach(el => {
  // Добавляем отсутствующие
  if (!seglist[el.seg]) arr1.push(el);
});

console.log(arr1)
```

---

Если уникального поля для этого нет([Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/642387/176064)), можно в качестве ключа использовать сериализованный объект: `JSON.stringify(el)`.

Если объекты слишком велики - многократная сериализация может стать слишком накладной.
Можно попробовать другой алгоритм, с сортировкой (асимптотика не лучше О(nlogn)):

```js
let arr1 = [{name: 'Alex', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Junior Dev'}, {name: 'John', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Middle Dev'}, {name: 'David', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Team Lead'} ];
let arr2 = [{name: 'Alex', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Junior Dev'}, {name: 'John', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Team Lead'}, {name: 'Den', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Team Lead'} ];

// Выбираем наиболее уникальное(имеющее большее количество уникальных значений поле), здесь это name

// Группируем объекты по этому полю
let objlist = arr1.reduce((o, el) => {
    if (!o[el.name]) o[el.name] = [];
    o[el.name].push(el);
    return o;
}, {});

const objEquals = (o1, o2) => {
    // В общем случае, проверку здесь можно сделать более полной, например, если порядок ключей может различаться
    return JSON.stringify(o1) === JSON.stringify(o2);
}

// Проходим по второму массиву
arr2.forEach(el => {
  // Добавляем отсутствующие
  if (!objlist[el.name]) arr1.push(el);
  else {
    // Некто с таким же именем уже есть в первом массиве
    for (let i = 0; i < objlist[el.name].length; ++i) {
        let o = objlist[el.name][i];
        let exists = false
        
        if (objEquals(o, el)) {
            // Полное совпадение, выходим
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
        // Не нашли совпадения, дополняем первый массив
        if (!exists) arr1.push(el);
    }
  }
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для [Проверка двух массивов на идентичность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642387)

```js
var array = [
    { name: 'Alex', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Junior Dev' },
    { name: 'John', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Middle Dev' },
    { name: 'David', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Team Lead' }
];

var temp_array = [
    { name: 'Alex', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Junior Dev' },
    { name: 'John', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Middle Dev' },
    { name: 'Ben', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Senior Dev' },
    { name: 'David', city: 'Chicago', position: 'Team Lead' }
];

function createLookup(input) {
  var result = {};
  
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var current = result;
    for(var key in input[i]) {
      if (!current[input[i][key]])
        current[input[i][key]] = {};
      current = current[input[i][key]];
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

function existsInLookup(item, lookup) {
  var current = lookup;
  for (var key in item) {
    //console.log(key);
    //console.log(current[item[key]]);
    if (!current[item[key]])
      return false;
    current = current[item[key]];
  }
  return true;
}

var lookup = createLookup(array);
//console.log(lookup);
for (var i = 0; i < temp_array.length; i++) {
  var exists = existsInLookup(temp_array[i], lookup);
  console.log(exists);
  if (!exists) {
    array.push(temp_array[i]);
    console.log(temp_array[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Строишь дерево по всем ключам? Я правильно понял? Оно ведь всё ещё даст ложно-положительное срабатывание при перемешивании ключей?

Comment: @vp_arth Ух ты, приятно иметь дело с людьми, которых не объедешь на кривой козе :). Хотел ответить, что можно сортировать ключи, но не буду упорствовать.