# Проверка двух массивов на идентичность

Tags: javascript

Есть два массива, в которых некоторые элементы могут повторяться. Мне нужно добавить элементы из второго массива в первый так, чтобы в первом массиве оказались только абсолютно разные элементы. Например, первый массив:

```
let array = [
    {
        name: 'Alex',
        city: 'Chicago',
        position: 'Junior Dev'
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        city: 'Chicago',
        position: 'Middle Dev'
    },
    {
        name: 'David',
        city: 'Chicago',
        position: 'Team Lead'
    }
];
```

И второй массив:

```
let temp_array = [
    {
        name: 'Alex',
        city: 'Chicago',
        position: 'Junior Dev'
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        city: 'Chicago',
        position: 'Middle Dev'
    },
    {
        name: 'Ben',
        city: 'Chicago',
        position: 'Senior Dev'
    },
    {
        name: 'David',
        city: 'Chicago',
        position: 'Team Lead'
    }
];
```

Как видно, в обеих массивах структура данных и значения свойств идентичны, однако во втором массиве присутствует дополнительный элемент. Мне нужно, чтобы David с должностью Senior Dev из Чикаго оказался в первом массиве. Проблема состоит в том, что в массивах нету уникальных ключей, к которым можно обращаться. Перебирать каждое из значений в элементах не имеет смысла. В реальной задаче массив с данными несколько больше и будет огромная гора кода со сравнениями. Как это можно решить?

P.S. - ранее [я оставлял вопрос на StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634956/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-json-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?noredirect=1#comment896216_634956), связанный с этой же задачей, но алгоритм, предоставленный @vp_arth не сработал, поскольку он собирает ключи и сравнивает массивы по уникальным значениям ключей.

Comment: суть абсолютна одинаковая, в твоем случае вместо отдельного ключа можешь делать JSON.stringify - всему объекту например

Comment: Имеется в виду `o[el.seg] = true` => `o[JSON.stringify(el)] = true` и `if (!seglist[el.seg])` => `if (!seglist[JSON.stringify(el)])`

Comment: А лучше таки заведите уникальный ключ

Comment: @vp_arth данные генерирую не я, а API, поэтому завести уникальный ключ не выйдет. Тем не мене, ваш код сработал. Большое спасибо!